# Compiled and signed grails plug-in

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Is it possible to compile and sign grails plug-in? I am thinking about distributing my application logic using grails plug-in architecture and I do not want my client to be able to read that easily .groovy or to modify it. Is it possible to package it somehow or at least distribute only compiled .class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to compile and package groovy/java code into a jar and then use it in a grails app. (as Scott suggests) but these classes can not directly benefit from grails ie. no way to declare grails service, domain class or controller in a separate jar.

There is an issue in grails jira describing the same problem:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4956

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you need to think more traditional Java.

Create a JAR with your logic in it and sign the jar. Put the minimum Groovy code in the plugin. You have not stated where the logic is if it's a controller or GORM object so I am not sure what you looking for 100%.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since Grails 1.4 M1 there are [binary plugins](http://www.grails.org/1.4.0.M1+Release+Notes), I assume this is exactly what you need. I'm not sure if signing is supported in any way, but it's at least possible to distribute the plugin without its sources.

Comment: yep, it seems binary plugin disto is available. I wonder why they didn't update te jira item mentioned in accepted answer. And once you have the jar, you can sign it...